# How foreach loop works?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

```
IMongoCollection<JobInfoRecord> records = ...
foreach (var record in records.Find(query).ToListAsync().Result)
{...}
```

Is it true that foreach iteration I compute `.Result` value again and again?

Comment: There is really no benefit to use the `Async` version of the `ToList` if you just call `.Result` on it. You should `await` it.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Because the point of asynchronous methods it to not block the thread, but by calling `Result` you are blocking the thread.  But since you want to iterate the results in your `foreach` there not much point in calling `ToListAsync` either.

Comment: But what should I calling instead of `.ToListAsync`?

Comment: There is no other method to get the `Result`, just `.ToListAsync().Result`

Comment: If the result of Find is Enumerable just do: `foreach (var record in records.Find(query)`

Comment: You might want to try `foreach(var record in await records.FindAsync(query))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's going to evaluate `records.Find(query).ToListAsync().Result` once and then call `GetEnumerator` on the result.  Then each loop is going to call `MoveNext` on the returned "Enumerator" and set `record` to the `Current` property of that "Enumerator" with the loop breaking when `MoveNext` returns `false`.